# Different definitions of volatility (simple question)

Tags: volatility, finance

I have a basic question on volatility that I wanted some clarification on.

In finance books (such as Hull), there's a few different ways volatility is defined. One of them is the standard deviation of yearly log returns, $R_i = \ln \frac{S_i}{S_{i-1}}$. Another is the standard deviation of the annual continuously compounded return rate, so the $x$ in $\exp(xT)$.

Both of these definitions make sense to me in terms of how they are derived and since the log returns and continuously compounded rates can be added up to give log returns and rates over longer time periods. For example: If we assume log returns (or rates) are normally distributed and independent, then if the random log return for year 1 is $R_1$, the random log return for year 2 is $R_2$ (each with volatility $\sigma$), and the random log return for years 1 and 2 combined is $R^* = R_1 + R_2$ , then we can calculate the volatility over two years using $\text{Variance}(R_1 + R_2) = 2\sigma^2$, and so the volatility of $R^*$is $\sqrt{2}\sigma$. So we can calculate volatility for 1 year, 2 years, 1 day, and so on, by the usual square root of time scale factor.

Hull's book also mentions that volatility can be considered the standard deviation of the percentage change in price, $\frac{dS}{S}$. I know that this makes sense since the SDE for $\frac{dS}{S}$ is normally distributed with variance $\sigma{\Delta t}$, but I was wondering why the values $\frac{S_i - S_{i-1}}{S_{i-1}}$ when added up don't have to lead to percentage changes in price of the longer time periods like log returns and continously compounded rates do. I was thinking it could be since for small percentage changes the log returns are approximately equal to the percentage changes. I'm not sure if this correct though.

I might be missing something obvious here, so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi: That's correct: The percent returns $\frac{S_i - S_{i-1}}{S_{i-1}}$ will provide a close approximation to the log returns  as long as $\triangle t$ is small enough. It's when $\triangle t$ gets too big, that the approximation becomes poor.

Comment: Your title is about volatility, but you ask a question about the return. You might want to make it consistent.
Regarding the question: you have to consider a product of $(1+ \frac{S_i - S_{i-1}}{S_{i-1}})$ to get a percentage change of the longer time, rather than the sum